# Compressing a video file in python with the standard library

Tags: python, compression

Is there a way to effectively compress a video file with the standard library of python? I wrote a quick script to accomplish this, but it barely compresses the video file. Take a look:

```
import sys
import zlib

with open('Some_Video.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    original_data = f.read()
    original_size = sys.getsizeof(original_data)

compress_data = zlib.compress(original_data, level=5)
compressed_size = sys.getsizeof(compress_data)

print(original_size)
print(compressed_size)
```

This was the output:

```
2793876
2788282
```

Why is the difference so small, and how can I compress further?

Comment: I don’t understand why this would be downvoted. The question was clearly asked, and the code was given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video files are already compressed. You cannot compress them further, at least not significantly.

Your only option would be to *decompress* them, and then recompress them with a more effective compressor, e.g. HEVC.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess there's no good way to do it with the standard library? I used HandBrake, and it reduced it to half the size. I was just wondering if I could be that efficient with python alone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the small reduction in file size is due zlib being a lossless compression library, and mp4 is already a compressed format so there's little margin to improvement.

From the standard library, [lzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) claims to have the best compression ratio. But keep in mind it's also lossless so I would not expect that much difference.

I recommend you use the third-party lib [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). It's a wrapper for the command line application ffmpeg, which would let you transcode your mp4 using better encoders like h265.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look into lzma for sure. I have heard of ffmpeg before, but I just started learning HandBrake open source. Do you prefer it over HandBrake?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience neither with ffmpeg or handbrake, sorry